# Adding prefix commend in output text file from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have created below powershell script to send the output file count from three different sources of file location and is working fine. However, the output file only has the number of count in it. I would like to add the comment before the results like "The total number of file count is"  and also like to add the source file location in the file along with count. Please help!!

Also the query seems to be very long and needs to be customized.

```
$input="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\*"
$input1="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\testcount2"
$input2="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\testcount2"

$output="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\finaloutput\finaloutput.txt"
$output1="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\finaloutput\finaloutput1.txt"
$output2="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\finaloutput\finaloutput2.txt"


$readcontent=Get-Content $output
$readcontent1=Get-Content $output1
$readcontent2=Get-Content $output2

$date=Get-Date



Get-ChildItem $input -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}|Set-Content -Path $output
Get-ChildItem $input1 -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}|Set-Content -Path $output1 
Get-ChildItem $input2 -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}|Set-Content  -Path $output2

Tried appending the output file by using -Value but did not work.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exporting this as CSV, `Get-ChildItem` can take multiple paths as input, then you can use `Group-Object` to group the files by their parent directory (`DirectoryName`) and then create your desired output:

```
$inputPaths = @(
    'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\'
    'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\testcount2'
    'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\testcount3'
)
$outputPath = 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\testcount\finaloutput\finaloutput.txt'

Get-ChildItem $inputPaths -File |
    Group-Object DirectoryName -NoElement |
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Path      = $_.Name
            FileCount = $_.Count
        }
    } | Export-Csv $outputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi, this worked great! thank you. I also need to generate a seperate log file to know if the complete process was successful or not with time stamp. every time should overwrite the old entires to avoid space issues.Can you help me with that